# Can you use the Marascuillo procedure for a contingency table with more than 3 rows?

Tags: chi-squared-test

When obtaining a significant result on a Chi-square test of a contingency table with 2 rows and c columns where c > 2, the Marascuilo procedure should be performed to interrogate the proportions (row 1/ [row total]), in order to find which proportions differ among the column pairs (column 1 vs 2, 1 vs 3, ... 1 vs c and 2 vs 3, ... 2 vs c, etc.)

When faced with c > 2 columns AND r > 2 rows, is there a way to test for the difference of proportions? In my understanding, the Marascuilo procedure could still be performed, but first of all it explodes quickly in terms of calculations needed, and second of all it may miss pattern differences if two columns have a "significantly" different pattern distribution when observing all rows together, but not per sé when regarding only proportions between 2 rows at a time.

My teachers only ever explained a 2 * c case, and when I ask llm-assisted search engines they give internally inconsistent answers, and the sources they quote also only discuss 2 * c cases.